# how to install ionic cordova local notification extension?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I am trying to install local notification by command "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification" and also "ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification" both are not installing. Can anyone please help me to install this extension please?
Here the screenshot I attached to this. For error support and also ionic info [image]

[image]

Comment: please run command `ionic info` and add result to your question.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I added the desired screenshot. please help me out

Comment: looks like you are using wrong nodejs version. Please download `14.17.1 LTS` version and install it.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I installed all you told. but not working same problem going on.